# how to align text and colons in straight line responsive

Tags: html, css

```
 aaa       :111
 bbbbbbb   :22222
 cccccccccc:33333333
 dd        :44
 eeee      :5555
```

It should be responsive, I tried it but the text which is right side of colon is going below to the left side in mobile view. It is ok if the right side text is coming to right side when the screen size is reduced.please give me suggestions for my problem.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and CSS you have right now?  I'm having a hard time visualizing what your code might be, what it currently looks like in the browser, and how you'd like it to look.

Comment: it if is tabular data - then use `<table>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using table option in HTML. Please try below snippet:

```css
table tbody tr td {
          text-align: left;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }


        table tbody tr td:nth-child(2):before {
          content: ":";
          display: inline-block;
          padding-left:10px; 
          margin-right:10px; 
        }
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>111</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbbbbbb</td>
        <td>22222</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cccccccccc</td>
        <td>33333333</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dd</td>
        <td>44</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>eeee</td>
        <td>5555</td>        
      </tr>
    </tbody>    
  </table>
```